# Stop Axis Stub creation in ant build.xml

Tags: xml, build, ant, axis, stub

As I was using Axis Jar before, to create Stub Classes from WSDL in ant build.xml, but faced some issues in Axis Jar. So I moved to CXF Jar creation to generate Stub Classes but I didn't cleanup the Axis Jar in build.xml. Now to remove the Axis Jar in build.xml File, should I provide any instructions to stop the Axis Stub creation or should I just delete the Axis related instructions in build.xml ?

I tried to comment the Axis related instructions in ant build.xml File and ran build in terminal but Axis Stubs are still generated. I want only CXG stubs and not the one created by Axis Jar.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.